# What happend to my RNN states when the input change from one batch to another

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a theoretical question based on RNN. As we all know, RNN have hidden states and it holds its previous time step information. 
While working with RNN we also batch our input data for better performance. I am talking about pre-processing of the data(not training batching of 32).

My question is, what happens to the RNN states when we switch from one batch to another. Do they hold the value from previous batch or reset them?

Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: with a lot of google search and my simulation, I think it kind of resets its value from one batch to another(no state info passed). So to get a better result, while converting the data into batches, we should give some transient data to get a better state value for the first unique input sequence.

Comment: If anyone have different findings, please share them